# How to create a page with twig?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, commerce

I want to customize the product page using twig.

I copy the `page.html.twig` file of my theme and I rename it in `page--product.html.twig`

```
<div class="fixed-bg"></div>
<div class="i-large"></div>
<div class="i-medium"></div>
<div class="i-small"></div>

{# Navigation (collapsible first) #}
{% if page.navigation_collapsible_first %}
  <div id="navbar-collapse-first" class="navbar-collapse-first collapse width navbar-collapse-first-fixed-top">
    {{ page.navigation_collapsible_first }}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% set container = theme.settings.fluid_container ? 'container-fluid' : 'container' %}
{# Navbar #}
{% if page.navigation_menu_first or page.navigation_indicator_first or page.navigation_logo or page.navigation_indicator_second or page.navigation_menu_second or page.navigation_collapsible_first or page.navigation_collapsible_second %}
  {% block navbar %}
    {%
      set navbar_classes = [
        'navbar',
        theme.settings.navbar_inverse ? 'navbar-inverse' : 'navbar-default',
        theme.settings.navbar_position ? 'navbar-' ~ theme.settings.navbar_position|clean_class : container,
      ]
    %}
    <header{{ navbar_attributes.addClass(navbar_classes) }} id="navbar" role="banner">
      {% if not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}
        <div class="{{ container }}">
      {% endif %}
      <div class="navbar-header">
        {{ page.navigation_menu_first }}
        {{ page.navigation_notification_first }}
        {{ page.navigation_logo }}
        {{ page.navigation_menu_second }}
        {{ page.navigation_notification_second }}
        {# .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content #}
      </div>

      {% if not navbar_attributes.hasClass(container) %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </header>
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{# Navigation (collapsible second) #}
{% if page.navigation_collapsible_second %}
  <div id="navbar-collapse-second" class="navbar-collapse-second collapse width navbar-collapse-second-fixed-top">
    {{ page.navigation_collapsible_second }}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{# Main #}
{% block main %}
  <div role="main" class="main-container {{ container }} js-quickedit-main-content">
    <div class="row">

      {# Header #}
      {% if page.header %}
        {% block header %}
          <div class="col-sm-12" role="heading">
            {{ page.header }}
          </div>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}

      {# Sidebar First #}
      {% if page.sidebar_first %}
        {% block sidebar_first %}
          <aside class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
            {{ page.sidebar_first }}
          </aside>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}

      {# Content #}
      {%
        set content_classes = [
          page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second ? 'col-sm-6',
          page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-md-9',
          page.sidebar_second and page.sidebar_first is empty ? 'col-md-9',
          page.sidebar_first is empty and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-12'
        ]
      %}
      <section{{ content_attributes.addClass(content_classes) }}>

        {# Highlighted #}
        {% if page.highlighted %}
          {% block highlighted %}
            <div class="highlighted">{{ page.highlighted }}</div>
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Breadcrumbs #}
        {% if breadcrumb %}
          {% block breadcrumb %}
            {{ breadcrumb }}
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Action Links #}
        {% if action_links %}
          {% block action_links %}
            <ul class="action-links">{{ action_links }}</ul>
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Help #}
        {% if page.help %}
          {% block help %}
            {{ page.help }}
          {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Content #}
        {% block content %}
          <a id="main-content"></a>
          {{ page.content }}
        {% endblock %}
      </section>

      {# Sidebar Second #}
      {% if page.sidebar_second %}
        {% block sidebar_second %}
          <aside class="col-md-3" role="complementary">
            {{ page.sidebar_second }}
          </aside>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% if page.footer %}
  {% block footer %}
    <footer class="footer {{ container }}" role="contentinfo">
      {{ page.footer }}
    </footer>
  {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

If I add the code below, it does not work. The page is not modified :

```
{{ product.variation_sku}}
{{ product.variation_field_produit_sku_store}}
{{ product.variation_field_service_sku_store}}
{{ product.variation_field_abonnement_sku_store}}
{{ product.variation_price}}
{{ product.variations}}
```

I have another question :

- How to display a block view in a twig file ?
- With twig, what is the interest of a module like "Display Suite" ?
- Is there a twig file to modify only the content part of the page ?

Comment: This is only going to work if `page—product.html.twig` is a valid suggestion.

Comment: @Kevin I do not understand. How to print the price not example?